# to get all the values of the managed metadata column

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, term-set

I have a  managed meta data column in my list "Employee" named "Office Location".
the metadata column refers to a TermStore "headquarter".
How do i get all the values of the termstore in javascript to use in in a dropdown in a form

Answer (score 0):

Sample script for your reference. myStronglyTypedObj referenced from [here](http://www.stephanrocks.com/2017/05/25/load-sp-js-taxonomy-and-other-utilities-in-sharepoint-2013-2016-and-office-365/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        if (myStronglyTypedObj === undefined) {
            var myStronglyTypedObj = {};
        }

        myStronglyTypedObj = {
            // Object Globals 
            "g": {},
            // Pre-initialization functions ensure scripts SharePoint dependencies are loaded
            "preinit": function () {
                // Load necessary libraries
                SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
                    // Register what you need from SharePoint (in this case the term store)
                    SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.taxonomy.js', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));
                    // Load the registered items
                    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.taxonomy.js', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', myStronglyTypedObj.init());
                });
            },
            // The main Initialization function
            "init": function () {
                /* Check if SP.Taxonomy actually exists yet
                 * PLEASE NOTE that it's common that these objects aren't available, even if you've properly loaded them in the "preinit" function. 
                 * This bit of code checks if the object is available, and if it's not, waits for 200ms and then tries again until this object is loaded
                 */
                if (SP.Taxonomy) {
                    console.log("SP.Taxonomy ready... continuing scripts...");
                    myStronglyTypedObj.therest();
                } else {
                    console.log("SP.Taxonomy not ready...  set timeout and try again after 200ms");
                    setTimeout(myStronglyTypedObj.init, 200);
                }
            },
            "therest": function () {
                getTermsFormTermSet();
            }
        }
        // Run whatever pre-initialisation checks you need to, and then load "preinit" as the starting point, for instance 
        myStronglyTypedObj.preinit();
        function getTermsFormTermSet() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();            
            var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Mydoc2");            
            var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("MeataField");
            var txField = clientContext.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);

            clientContext.load(field);
            clientContext.load(txField);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var termSetId = txField.get_termSetId().toString();
                var tSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
                var ts = tSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
                var tset = ts.getTermSet(termSetId);               
                var terms = tset.getAllTerms();
                clientContext.load(terms);

                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                  function () {
                      var enumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
                      while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                          var spTerm = enumerator.get_current();
                          console.log(spTerm);
                      }

                  }, function (err) {
                      alert(err.get_message());
                  });
            },
             function error(err) {
                 alert(err.get_message());
             });

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: txField.get_termSetId().toString(); gives a error saying get_termSetID doesnot exist on type clientobj

Comment: The error seems caused by sp.taxonomy.js not loaded correctly, if you use developer tool to debug the script, will you see the library loaded correctly?